# Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I get this error message when use jQuery UI tabs: `Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.`

Using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery-UI 1.9.2 with this codes.

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#div_default">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div_size">Size</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div_advanced">Advanced</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="div_default">...</div>
    <div id="div_size">...</div>
    <div id="div_advanced">...</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
     $('.tabs').tabs();
     $('.tabs').removeClass('ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
     $('.tabs ul').addClass('ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
 });
```

If I'm falling back to jQuery-UI 1.8.23 then no error messages and same not working the tabs.

What is wrong here or how can I get more inforamtion form browser? (using Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

I used an older version of the `TinyMCE` with `jQuery`. If upgrad or remove the TinyMCE then everything working fine.